# Prove that $x^2 = - 1$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I have this proposition to prove: The equation $x^2 = -1$ has no solution in $\mathbb Z$.
I was told that this is an opportunity for a proof by contradiction. I have already proven that for $m \in\mathbb Z$, if $m \ne 0$ then $m^2 \in\mathbb N$. I have also proven that 1 is a natural number (hence, -1 isn't one).

Here is my strategy: assume that there is a solution. Hence $x^2$ has 3 options:
\begin{align*}
x^2 \in\mathbb N\\
-(x^2) \in\mathbb N\\
x^2 = 0
\end{align*}

Option 1 is not possible because -1 is not a natural number. Option 2 doesn't make sense because

-$\mathbb N \in \mathbb N$ and option 3 doesn't make sense either because $0 \ne -1$. What do you think? Thank you!

---

Here is a simpler strategy based on the comments below.

Proof: Assume that $x^2 = -1$ has a solution in $\mathbb Z$, then $x^2$ will either be $0$ or $\in\mathbb N$. However, $-1 \notin\mathbb N$ and $-1 \ne 0$. Hence, there is a contradiction. Here is how I have proven that $-1 \notin\mathbb N$: Let $m \in\mathbb N$. Hence:

\begin{align*}
-m \notin\mathbb N\\
(-1)m \notin\mathbb N
\end{align*}

If $-1 \in\mathbb N$, the product of $-1$ and $m$ should $\in\mathbb N$, which is not the case here. Hence, $-1 \notin\mathbb N$.

Comment: What does that $-\mathbb N \in \mathbb N$ mean?

Comment: You're right to do proof by contradiction, but I think you're going about a bit oddly. If $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x>0, x<0, or x=0$. Evidently $x=0$ doesn't work, so $x<0$ or $x>0$. If $x<0$, then $-x>0$ and $(-x)^2=(-1)^2x^2=x^2$. So it suffices to assume $x>0$. Now what?

Comment: It looks like you have everything you need already.  Since you've proven that if $m\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$, then $m^2\in\mathbb{N}$.  You also know that $-1\not\in\mathbb{N}$.  Then the contrapositive of if $m\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$, then $m^2\in\mathbb{N}$ gives you the result you're looking for.

Comment: @Michael Burr Actually, that was my first idea. However, I thought that my prof. wanted something "fancier" lol

Comment: You can always turn an if-then proof (or a contrapositive proof) into a contradiction.  It makes the proof longer, but if you'd like to argue a contradiction that works too.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you! But I your idea is simpler and better. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your solution makes sense. There's definitely something circular going on when you handle the second case - and I'm not sure how the structure of your proof was intended. It would be better to split into cases based on $x$, rather than $x^2$. In particular, a proof of this could run as follows:

- Suppose $x\geq 0$. Then $x^2\geq 0$. However $-1$ is not greater than or equal to $0$, and hence $x^2$ cannot be $-1$.
- Suppose $x\leq 0$. Then $x^2\geq 0$. Similarly as before, $x^2$ cannot be $-1$.

However, given that you've already shown that $x^2\in \mathbb N$ if $x\neq 0$, you already know that if $x\neq 0$ then $x^2\neq -1$ because $-1\not\in \mathbb N$. Since $0^2$ is also not $-1$, the theorem is proven.

Answer (score 2):

Any integral solution whose magnitude is greater than one is impossible, because the squared term would be too large. So you only have to check $\pm1$, and both fail.

Comment: This is the best proof.

Comment: @User0112358 agreed. +1.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to observe that $z^2+1=0$ has at most two complex solutions since the number of zeros of a polynomial is less than or equal to its degree. $i,-i$ are two such solutions so there are no others.  Neither of these is a natural number so there are no natural number solutions.

I call this approach "extension-uniqueness."

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to prove this by contradiction here.

Suppose instead there does exist a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$ to the equation $x^2=-1$. Algebra would tell us that the only solutions to that equation are $x=\pm i$. However, $i$ and $-i$ are both complex numbers. So $i$ and $-i$ are not real numbers, let alone not integers. (Note that $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$.) So $i,-i \not\in \mathbb{Z}$. This is the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The mos straight-forward technique is to show that $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. For a degree two polynomial $f(x)$ to be reducible it must have a liner factor, i.e a root $u$ satisfying $f(u)=0$. Here by the quadratic formula we know $x^2+1 = 0 \Rightarrow$

$$x = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{0^2-4}}{2} = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{-4}}{2} = \pm \sqrt{-1} = \pm i$$

Hence if $x^2+1$ were to factor it would do as the product $(x+i)(x-i)$, where neither $\pm i \in \mathbb{Z}$ (since if so the integers would be an ordered field).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a solution, then reduce $\mod 4$. There are no solutions to $x^{2} \equiv 3 \mod 4$ since the only squares $\mod 4$ are, $0$ and $1$. Thus you have a contradiction. But, this requires more work than Bill's solution. His solution only requires you to check 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Since 0^2+1=0+1=1(not equal to 0) ; then x€real number is not a solution of x^2+1=0
therefore x^2+1=0 has a non-zero solution.
Now we have to extablish the theorem by method of cotradiction.

Let the equation has real solution.

This is sufficient to prove that of any non-zero real number which is a solution of the equation. 
On its contrary. spose there exist x belongs to real numbers - {0} as a solution of the equation.

But x not equal to 0
Implies x^2>0
Implies x^2+1>0

For all x belongs to zero and x not equal to zero 
Imples x^2+1 not equal to zero

Which is a contradiction. 
So our assumption is wrong. 
As a result x^2+1=0 has no real solution.